# CSS list layout inside div

Tags: html, css

I've got the following css file :

```
.h_bg{
    height:100%;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
.h_bg h1{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:1;
    top: 23%;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:500%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    background-size:89px 183px;
}
```

and html page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
            <title>Beauty Up</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="h_bg">
        <h1>Beauty Up - mobile<br>service for you</h1>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Inside div bg container i want to add two more lines,closer to bottom ( email and phone ones ), with floating distance from `<h1>` to achieve the following effect :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making two classes - h2 and h3, specified top :

```
.h_bg h2{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:1;
    top: 73%;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.h_bg h3{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:1;
    top: 78%;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make another div inside the `h-bg` div and write css for it

```
padding-top: 222px;
```

Comment: yep, i've already done this. But it would calculate position relative to top of screen. Can i set top space from <h1>?

Comment: make new div inside the 'h-bg' div and try this css